# How to style the last element before another specific element in CSS?

Tags: css

So I would like to achieve this in CSS only, since I know how simply it is to do in jQuery.

Basically, I have a long list of `p` and `h4` elements, and I would like to style every last `p` element before the next `h4`. For example:

```
<h4>Heading</h4>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h4>Heading</h4>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h4>Heading</h4>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

In that list, every last `p` needs to be styled before the following `h4`.

The amount of `p` and `h4` tags on the page is always random.

Is something like this achieveable with CSS alone?

Comment: yes but you need to add class names. with out that it seems not possible to me..

Comment: That question asks for siblings, mine is asking for the last element after another element. Completely different questions. For example, that will not find the very last `p` tag.

Comment: `last element after another element === previous sibling` am I wrong? they sound same to me honestly..

Comment: Then explain to me, in reference to the example in my original question, how would the last `p` tag be styled if it does not have a `h4` tag after it to be the sibling of? They are completely different questions...

Comment: you were saying: "*last element after **another element***" now you are saying different. anyway, you can use `:last-child` pseudo class.

Comment: `last-child` of what though? Can't do the `last-child` of `h4` since they are not children of `h4`. All the code I posted within my example is within the same container...

Comment: no, I am saying something like this `p:nth-child(4), p:nth-child(7), p:last-child`.. but still mentioning the container would be good in this case. or else just adding a class to those elements in HTML or dynamically as shown by Rohit in below posts.

Comment: The main thing is, the elements are dynamically created upon page load. The amount of them is completely random and using `nth-child` just wouldn't work since there is no way to determine what number it is. It is now obvious that jQuery would be the only way, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is something like this achieveable with CSS alone?

Not yet.

If the [subject selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) gets implemented, then you'd be able to use:

```
!p + h4 {
    ...
}
```

However that specification is still in an early draft state, so implementation is a ways off. You'd be better off using classes for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

**Use jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('h4').prev('p').addClass('redCss'); // used to .prev and .next according to your requirement 
})
```

**With this class**

```
.redCss{

    color:red;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sk255/1/)**

more about in **[.prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)**

more about in **[.next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)**

more about in **[addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)**

Comment: This question isn't tagged javascript or jQuery, however since CSS won't work _vanilla js_ should be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**:nth-child**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) pseudo class (*would be better to use if you know the pattern of repetition*).

**CSS**

```
p:nth-child(4), p:nth-child(7){
    color: red;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/TJF9E/)

**or else**

Adding a class to each `p` element which is just before `h4` element is also a good approach.