# How to get last-child of each heading?

Tags: html, css

Suppose this HTML:

```
<h1>heading</h1>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>bar</p><!---this should be selected--->

<h1>heading</h1>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>bar</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>bar</p><!---this should be selected--->
```

And to select this only with CSS is not possible?

I was trying it like this:

```
h1 ~ p:last-child /*wouldn't work*/ /* it would select last-child of p*/
```

Comment: h1 p:last-child{ ....  }

Comment: @ShibinRagh it won't work. it's invalid. h1 hasn't child

Comment: Can we wrap on complete P tag ?

Comment: sorry, no. I was looking for this without modifying html something like nth-child(-1) or only-of-type() but couldn't find to work

Comment: now go to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496160/how-to-style-the-last-element-before-another-specific-element-in-css/22496198#22496198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply not possible with CSS, as there is no way to select elements backward or up the tree (looking forward to CSS4…). You will have to use one of these:

```
<section>
    <h1>heading</h1>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p><!---this should be selected--->
</section>
```

(`section p:last-child`) Or:

```
<h1>heading</h1>
<p>foo</p>
<p class="last">bar</p><!---this should be selected--->
```

(`p.last`) Or with JS:

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    var f = e[i].nextSibling;
    while (f && f.tagName == 'P') {
        var n = f.nextSibling();
        if (!n) {
            f.classList.add('last');
        } else {
            f = n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing for previous or next siblings but searching for css something like only-of-type....

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvpatel/aY674/8/)

```
<div class="span8">
<h1>heading</h1>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>bar</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>bar</p>
</div>    

  .span8 > p:last-child{ color:red }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the content with a `div`, then it is possible using `CSS`.

```
div p:last-child  {
  color:red;
}
```

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e24zr/)

Answer (score -1):

It is possible with Jquery. Here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ayazshah/sk255/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('h1').prev('p').addClass('myclass');
})
```

Learn more about previous and next on this [**link**](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Comment: Won't get the last one.